# How to declare types to use vue-simple-svg in typescript vue3

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am trying to load this module in a typescript vue3 project in main.ts

```
import {SimpleSVG} from 'vue-simple-svg'
Vue.component('simple-svg', SimpleSVG)
```

Visual Studio code flags it as an typing error:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'vue-simple-svg'.
'C:/source/TrexStaticWebsite/node_modules/vue-simple-svg/dist/plugin.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try `npm i --save-dev @types/vue-simple-svg` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'vue-simple-svg'
```

Answer (score 0):

That library is written for Vue 2, so you can't use it in a Vue 3 project (unless you use Vue's [migration build](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/migration-build.html)).

Also, the library has no typings defined for it, so you'll encounter the error you observed. Follow the suggestion from the error message (`add a new declaration (.d.ts) file`), and declare your own typings for it by creating this file in your project root:

```js
// src/vue-simple-svg.d.ts
declare module 'vue-simple-svg'
```